How to Hide Save-As Icons in query results
On the right side of every query result is a vertical bar of icons to SaveAs the data in various formats (CSV, Excel, JSON, Markdown, XML).



I often run several queries that return a single row and I have no intention of exporting the result. This SaveAs bar is 2-3 times the height of each result leading to gaps of whitespace. I would prefer to eliminate this whitespace to see more results without scrolling.
I have two questions:

Is there a configuration setting that will hide it, and less importantly,
What is this SaveAs bar officially called ?


I found the setting and the name of the bar.
It is the Results: Show Action Bar.

Alternatively, you can add "queryEditor.results.showActionBar": false, to your settings.json to hide it.
